# Janusgraph enable ConfiguredGraphFactory in test container

Tags: janusgraph, testcontainers

I am using test container with Janusgraph, but I need to use ConfiguredGraphFactory in my test. How to enable it in test container? This is how I am starting the test container:

```
        GenericContainer<JanusGraph> janus = new JanusGraph()
            .withNetwork(network)
            .withExposedPorts(JANUS_PORT)
            .waitingFor(Wait.forListeningPort())
            .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
            .withEnv("janusgraph.storage.backend", "cql")
            .withEnv("janusgraph.storage.hostname", storageName)
            .withEnv("janusgraph.index.search.backend", "elasticsearch")
            .withEnv("janusgraph.index.search.hostname", indexName)
            .withEnv("janusgraph.schema.default", "tp3");
```

I was trying to add `.withEnv("janusgraph.graph.graphname"."org.janusgraph.core.ConfiguredGraphFactory")` but it doesn't work (image name: janusgraph/janusgraph:0.5.3).

Answer (score 0):

The example yaml and properties files for trying ConfiguredGraphFactory can be found at:
[conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server-configuration.yaml](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/v0.6.2/janusgraph-dist/src/assembly/static/conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server-configuration.yaml)
[conf/janusgraph-cql-configurationgraph.properties](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/v0.6.2/janusgraph-dist/src/assembly/cfilter/conf/janusgraph-cql-configurationgraph.properties)

It is described in the [janusgraph-docker](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph-docker/blob/master/README.md) project that you can define `gremlin.* and janusgraph.*` environment variables in your Dockerfile to override the default configs. Your approach with GenericContainer.withEnv() should be fine too.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at this [JanusGraph PR](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph-docker/pull/55), I think this approach should work:

```
.withEnv("gremlin.graph"."org.janusgraph.core.ConfiguredGraphFactory")
```

However, I have no experience with JanusGraph and I think this is not a Testcontainers-specific question. This means you can conceptually configure it for Testcontainers the same way to would configure it for a Docker container with the Docker CLI.